# Uniqueness of measure by Laplace transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\Omega=[0,\infty)$, and $\mu$ and $\nu$ be measures including $\{[a,b)|0\leq a \leq b \leq \infty\}$.

Suppose for all natural numbers $n$, their Laplace transformations are coincide, they are same measure.
$F(z):=\int e^{-\frac{x}{z}}d\mu (x), G(z):=\int e^{-\frac{x}{z}}d\nu (x)$, then $F(\frac{1}{n})=G(\frac{1}{n})$ and $\lim \frac{1}{n} =0$. So if $F$ and $G$ are holomorophic on domain including $0$ ,then $F=G$. But I can't prove holomorophism.

Comment: Is there any reason this is different to the question you asked yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752971/uniqueness-of-finite-borel-measure-on-0-infty)? I can't see a reason that your new idea shouldn't have just been edited into that question.

Comment: Frankly, I didn't like that [you deleted the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2751749/8157). I was following it, because I found it interesting, and I invested a bit of time in reading and commenting. Now I discover that it was just the "rough copy" of this one, and that you threw it away. Please try to avoid this behavior in the future.

Comment: ?? It is not copy, because this approach is complex analysis. It is difficult to try to answer by previous approach, so I deleted in order to avoid reader's confusion.

Comment: Well, the reasoning we were doing in comments to the deleted question was heading exactly in the direction of David's answer below (the one with Stone-Weierstrass). The answer was almost there. Anyway, it's OK, no worries. (FYI, on this site it is considered bad practice to open multiple questions on the same problem; it is better to edit the same question to include new developments, as Rhys pointed out.)

Comment: Well, I contacted the moderators and it turned out that you were right, and I were wrong. You had the right to delete your question as long as the comments did not contain full answers. Therefore, I apologize for my previous message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z)=\int e^{-zx} d\mu(x)$ and $g(z)=\int e^{-zx} d\nu(x)$ are holomorphic in $\Omega \equiv \{z \in \mathbb C :\Re z>0\}$. [you can prove this by directly showing differentiability]. The map $z \to \frac 1 z$ maps $\Omega$ onto itself. Since $f(\frac 1 z)$ and $g(\frac 1 z)$ coincide at the points $\frac 1 n, n \geq 1$, $n$ odd they are equal on $\Omega$. Hence $\int e^{-tx} d\mu(x)=\int e^{-tx} d\mu(x)$ for all $t>0$ and this implies $\mu =\nu$.

Comment: One way of proving that the function $f$ in my answer is holomorphic is to first prove that when you integrate from $0$ to $N$ you get a holomorphic function and these converge uniformly on compact subsets to $f$. [ Note that if $K$ is compact in $\Omega$ then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\Re z >\delta$ for all $z \in K$.

Comment: ??? Why should $f(n)=g(n)$ for odd $n$, or $f(1/n)=g(1/n)$ or both, imply $f=g$?

Answer (score 3):

Your $F$ and $G$ are holomorphic in $\Omega=\{\Re z>0\}$ (a clean way to see this is to first show they're continuous and then apply Morera's Theorem). Alas $0$ is just a boundary point of $\Omega$, so the argument doesn't quite work, or at least it's not quite that simple.

One way to fix it is to show that $F$ and $G$ are *bounded* and to note that the sequence $1/n$ violates the Blaschke condition regarding zero sets of bounded holomorphic functions in a half-plane.

That uses moderately "advanced" complex analysis. There's a simple real-variables proof: Define two new measures by $d\mu'(x)=e^{-x}d\mu(x)$ and $d\nu'(x)=e^{-x}d\nu(x)$. So $\mu'$ and $\nu'$ satisfy the same hypothesis, except for *even* $n$. Stone-Weierstrass shows that $\int\phi d\mu'=\int\phi d\nu'$ for every $\phi\in C_0([0,\infty))$; hence $\mu'=\nu'$.

Comment: There's a version of S-W for $C_0(X)$ where $X$ is locally compact. I believe it's in Folland; if not it must exist on Wikipedia. Or, more or less equivalently, regard $e^{-nx}$ as a continuous function on $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: Yes. In the notation that's standard with many authors the space  of functions with compact support is $C_c(X)$. (Which is dense in $C_0(X)$.)